# difference between "Coverage summary by istance" and "Design Unit Coverage Details"

Tags: fpga, questasim

In an FPGA project what is the difference between:

1. Coverage summary by istance
2. Local Istance Coverage Details
3. Recursive Hierarchical Coverage Details
4. Design Unit Coverage Details

Answer (score 0):

These are mainly hardware verification terminologies. And also to some extent simulation tool specific terminologies. StackOverflow post about [Testing FPGA Designs at Different Levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381619/testing-fpga-designs-at-different-levels) is may be helpful for you.

In FPGA development there are some mission critical sectors where you need a maximum functional coverage (functional verification of every requirement) and code coverage like statement, branch, expression, conditions etc. Hence you lay out coverage plans.

For instance, [Advanced FPGA
Design Architecture, Implementation, and Optimization](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Steve-Kilts/dp/0470054379) mentions about FPGA based coverage as follows:

> Due to the ability of an FPGA to rapidly prototype the design and to
> run vectors real-time in hardware, the development time for gate-level code coverage
> is rarely justified. That said, code coverage can still be useful at the gate
> level as it is at the RTL level. When running a gate-level simulation, the code
> coverage analysis will provide a coverage number relative not to the logical
> constructs but to the physical elements themselves.

Having said that, you will find explicit differences about these terminologies at [Forums: Coverage](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/coverage/all/functional-coverage) of [Verification Academy](https://verificationacademy.com/). For example, in this forum you will find [Different coverage report for different covergroup instance](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/coverage/different-coverage-report-different-covergroup-instance)